# Уменьшение всего контента сайта при уменьшении окна браузера

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, scss

У меня есть страница без адаптива. Я прописал
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1440, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />`
дело в том, что когда я уменьшаю разрешение через панель разработчика всё работает как нужно, сайт уменьшается. Если я пытаюсь сжать само окно браузера то у меня содержимое сайта не уменьшается. а появляется горизонтальный скролл. Подскажите как решить проблему.

Comment: meta viewport работает только на мобильных браузерах. Видимо вы в панели разработчика включаете режим эмуляции мобильника, но это не тот режим в котором браузер работает обычно.

Comment: а вообще есть такая возможность, чтобы при сжатии именно браузера сайт так же сжимался как на мобилках?